# Simple Probléme in wordpress

Tags: php, functions

Hello members I have a simple problem.

I am Beginner in WordPress but I'm programming a website.
The website has two pages: the first is the index and the second is an extra page.

I upload the site in WordPress and edit the links to suit the platform, the index page it's worked but when you press the View videos شاهد الفيديوهات and move on to the second page, it does not work. I tried reuploading the second page again but it still didn't work.

This my Website URL : http://tes4t.co.nf/

These my files :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGbyj.png

This is the code that i used in the transition from page to page :

```
 <div class="box" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/page1.php';" >
```

my page1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style1.css"/>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min3.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/youmax.min.js"></script>
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/youmax.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".cssload-container").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
        </head>
    <body>

 <div class="box">    
        <div class="logo">
     <img src="https://s27.postimg.org/6gwfnvysz/image.png"/>    
     </div>
        </div>
 <div class="youmax">
        </div>       
    </body>
    <script src="js/snowstorm.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".youmax").youmax({
        channelLink:"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCa7lQu3RM6p88h4KOfTpqWA",
        playlistLink:"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTCHQ_SIzkGRMKaFR8x0w4mfpLrooKjxW",
        apiKey:"AIzaSyAlhAqP5RS7Gxwg_0r_rh9jOv_5WfaJgXw",
        maxResults:"9",
        videoDisplayMode:"popup",
        defaultTab:"Uploads",
        hideHeader:false,
        hideTabs:false,
        hideLoadingMechanism:false,
    });
});
    </script>
    <script>$("html").niceScroll();</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ahlan va sahlan, please add your _page1.php_ file's content to your question (or it's important parts if the file is too long)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to give a little more explanation.

But I think that the problem is that you are using `get_template_directory_uri()` as an anchor link. What `get_template_directory_uri()` does is to give you the URL of your theme, for instance you can get your "/assets/images" folder like this.

If your site structure is "theme_folder/page1.php" then I recommend you to better use a [Page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/)

Page templates let you create a new page from WP Admin and have an specific design of yours.